# How to get only an specific piece of JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api, jsonparser

This is my first time with JavaScript, I know its awful hahaha!

I'm looking for a way to display only the `currentDateTime` value from the JSON, the number after the `T` to be more specific, when clicking the button, but every time I click on the button, It displays all the JSON data. Is there a better way to do this, I mean, a correct way?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>World Clock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="msg">World Clock</h1>
    <p class="dsc">Click one of the buttons to see the current time</p>

    <button class="btn1" onclick="estFunc()">Eastern Standard Time (EST)</button>
```

```js
fetch('http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => time = data)
    .then(() => console.log(time["currentDateTime"]))

function estFunc() {
    const obj = {time};
    const estJson = JSON.stringify(obj);
    document.getElementById("est").innerHTML = estJson;
}
```

Comment: That depends on the server. You only can get a "certain amount" if the server supplies such an API, which it doesn't appear to.

Comment: @Mili Sousa, could you try out one of the answers?

Comment: @sandrooco Yes! Your answer was really helpful! Now when I use the button, only the "currentDateTime" portion of the API shows, but I still need to figure out a way to specify a little more this string. For now It shows: {"time":"2022-01-18T15:45-05:00"}", what should I do in order to display only the time portion? I'm looking at the first answer but I don't understand the logic behind it in order to reformat the time. Thanks a lot all!!

Comment: In this case currentDateTime is an object, in it `time` is the key and `"2022-01-18T15:45-05:00"` is the value. I adjusted my answer accordingly.
See this documentation on how objects work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects
Please also consider marking this as solved if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const estFunc = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
  const data = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
  // do something with JSON
  document.getElementById("est").innerHTML = data.currentDateTime;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>World Clock</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="msg">World Clock</h1>
  <p class="dsc">Click one of the buttons to see the current time</p>
  <button class="btn1" onclick="estFunc()">Eastern Standard Time (EST)</button>
  <div id="est"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are not wrong but don't provide an explanation on what's wrong.
Your problem is that you `stringify` the whole object you get from the server, not just the `currentDateTime`.

```
fetch('http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => time = data.currentDateTime.time) // only assign currentDateTime.time instead of everything
    .then(() => console.log(time.currentDateTime.time))
```